# While fetching facebook data it throws facebook network exception and java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: me/feed?

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookNetworkException: A network error occurred while trying to communicate with Facebook: Facebook request failed (HTTP status code null)
    at 
 com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookC
  lient.java:1024)
    at 
 com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchConnectionPage(DefaultFacebookClient.java
    :374)
    at main.main(main.java:26)

    Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: me/feed
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor.execute(DefaultWebRequestor.java:365)
    at com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor.executeGet(DefaultWebRequestor.java:96)
    at 

  com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$2.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:377)
    at 
 com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookC
   lient.java:1022)
    ... 2 more

   Java Result: 1
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is my error 
   when I try to fetch the `user_posts` on my application the request doesn't send 
   properly. How to resolve this?

```
    /*
    * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project
    Properties.
    * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    * and open the template in the editor.
    */

    /**
    *
    * @author User
    */
    import com.restfb.Connection;
    import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
    import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
    import com.restfb.types.Post;
    import java.util.*;

    public class main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accesstoken="EAACEdEose0cBAAXB6i9nmi0VJSZCHI******************";        
        FacebookClient fbclient=new DefaultFacebookClient(accesstoken);
        Connection<Post> result=fbclient.fetchConnectionPage("me/feed", 
                                                               Post.class);        
        int counter=0;

        for(List<Post>page : result)
        {
         for(Post aPost:page)
         {
          System.out.println(aPost.getMessage());
          System.out.print(aPost.getId());
          counter++;        
         }
        }
        System.out.println(" counter "+counter);

    }

   }
```

In this code, access token was got from Developer option.

Answer (score 0):

Per the RestFB API for fetchConnectionPage (http://restfb.com/javadoc-2/com/restfb/DefaultFacebookClient.html#fetchConnectionPage-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) you need to pass in a proper URL.

So basically on this line:

```
Connection<Post> result=fbclient.fetchConnectionPage("me/feed", Post.class);
```

instead of passing in "me/feed" you need to pass in a fully formed URL, like "http://facebook.com/me/feed" or whatever that URL should be.

This is also implied to you by the MalformedURLException, since you're passing in what should be a URL; that hints that you're not providing an accurate URL.

Comment: Super that exception was cleared but still it shows error on Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookNetworkException: A network error occurred while trying to communicate with Facebook: Facebook request failed (HTTP status code 301)
 at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1035)
 at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchConnectionPage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:374)
 at main.main(main.java:25)
Java Result: 1